# Routing is not triggerd with useEffect in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a dynamic page in Nextjs -> steps -> [slug].tsx . Essentially, it is a steps page and routing is triggered whenever a step changes in the state. For example, if I am in the first step, its value is null but once I click next its value becomes "next". When I go back I basically null the step and useEffect should react to these changes and route. However, it doesn't seem to work. I am not sure why.

Here is my code

```
type Steps = {
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  value: string | null;
};

const StepsPage: NextPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { query } = router;
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState<Steps[]>([
    {
      title: "Step 1",
      slug: "step-1",
      value: null,
    },
    {
      title: "Step 2",
      slug: "step-2",
      value: null,
    },
    {
      title: "Step 3",
      slug: "step-3",
      value: null,
    },
  ]);

  let step: Steps | undefined = undefined;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!steps) {
      return;
    }

    const nextStep = steps.find((step) => step.value === null);
    if (nextStep && step && step.slug !== nextStep.slug) {
      console.log("go to next step");
      router.push(`/steps/${nextStep.slug}`);
      return;
    }
    if (!nextStep) {
      router.push("/result");
      return;
    }
  }, [router, steps, step]);

  if (!steps) {
    <div>no steps found</div>;
  }

  const slug = Array.isArray(query.slug) ? query.slug[0] : query.slug;
  if (!slug) {
    return <div>no slug found</div>;
  }

  const currentStep = steps.find((step) => step.slug === slug);

  if (!currentStep) {
    return <div>no current step found</div>;
  }
  const handleStep = (value: string | null) => {
    setSteps((prevSteps) => {
      const updatedSteps = prevSteps.map((step) => {
        if (step.slug === slug) {
          return { ...step, value };
        }
        return step;
      });
      return updatedSteps;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Step Page</h1>
      <p>Slug: {slug}</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleStep("next")}>Next</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleStep(null)}>Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StepsPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the logic might just be a little jumbled. Here's what I'd recommend.

First, it looks like the steps themselves are static. I would make your `Step` type simply

```
type StepSlug = "step1" | "step2" | "step3"; // Extra type safety

interface Step {
  title: string;
  slug: StepSlug;
};
```

Then, I would declare the following array *outside* of the component, since it is static.

```
const STEPS: Step[] = [
  step1: {
    title: "Step One",
    slug: "step1",
  },
  // same for step2 and step3
];
```

Then, within your component, you have the following state:

```
const StepsPage = () => {
  ...
  const [stepIx, setStepIx] = useState(0);
  const [values, setValues] = useState<(string | null)[]>(STEPS.map(() => null)); // creates initial values of array, same length as STEPS, with all null values
  ...
  // Not necessary but for readability
  const currentStep = STEPS[stepIx];
  const canGoForward = stepIx < STEPS.length - 1;
  const canGoBackward = stepIx > 0;
  const goForward = () => {
    if (!canGoForward) return;
    setStepIx((val) => val + 1);
  }
  const goBackward = () => {
    if (!canGoBackward) return;
    setStepIx((val) => val - 1);
  }
  // Helper functions
  const updateCurrentValue = (newVal: string) => {
    setValues((oldValues) => {
      oldValues[stepIx] = newVal;
      return oldValues;
    }
  };
  ...
  // Here's how you listen to changes to the step
  useEffect(() => {
    ... // logic for setting the slug
  }, [stepIx]);
  ...
}
```

Obviously there's still a bit to fill in, but this is both safer (w.r.t types) and lets `stepIx` serve as the source of truth combined with the `STEPS` array so you don't have to keep searching for the slug.